# Cleanup user data from Cloud Firestore after sign out a user

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I write a function witch cleanup all user data (collections, sub-collections, and images) from **Cloud Firestore** after he signs out from the account.

For this, I use the code from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections).

My code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
//const bucket = admin.storage().bucket("gs://movere-point.appspot.com/");

exports.recursiveDelete = functions.runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
})
.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {

    // const path = data.path;
    const path = "/Users/" + user.uid;

    console.log(path);

    return firebase_tools.firestore.delete(path, {
        project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: ""
    })
    .then(() => {
        return {
            path: path 
        };
    });
});
```

I remove a user from the Firebase console, and in the log of Function, I get the error:

```
Error
    at new FirebaseError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/error.js:9:18)
    at module.exports (/srv/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:38:12)
    at Request._callback (/srv/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:39:35)
    at Request.self.callback (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
```

Help solve the problem with the removal of all user data after the user leaves the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in your question is incorrect. However, I guess you refer to this documentation item: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

You will note in this example the use of a token when doing:

```
return firebase_tools.firestore
  .delete(path, {
    project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
    token: functions.config().fb.token
  })
```

**In your code you have assigned an empty value to this token, which is the reason of the error you encounter.**

You need to do as follows, using the Firebase CLI in a terminal:

```
firebase login:ci
```

You will get a token value like:

```
✔  Success! Use this token to login on a CI server:

Z/A01c9zOI74FUgPJm5aEN9d2XyTKPgQkRlePQigxBBCSOUQ_0ktLW4mfAX3x4rFLL
```

Then you need to store it as environment configuration data. Since the token value is `functions.config().fb.token` you should do:

```
firebase functions:config:set fb.token="Z/A01c9zOI74FUgPJm5aEN9d2XyTKPgQkRlePQigxBBCSOUQ_0ktLW4mfAX3x4rFLL"
```

Then re-deploy the Cloud Functions and you should be ok!

Comment: here `token: "TOKEN"` I need to set token of a user which is necessary to remove?

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand your comment. Just follow the explanations in the answer: you generate a token value and you store it in the config data.

Comment: Oooh... I understood my mistake. Thank you!